# C++ version of MATLAB code that reads raw image bytes from file and reshapes them to image dimensions

Tags: c++, image, matlab

I have some simple MATLAB code that reads a RAW file, representing an image, reshapes and transposes the data to image dimensions and then shows the image:

```
    width = 640;
    height = 480;
    fin = fopen('image.raw','r');
    I = fread(fin, width * height, 'uint8=>uint8'); 
    img = reshape(I, width, height);
    img = img';
    imgFromRaw = imshow(img)
```

How do I produce the same code in C++, either using a vector to read the raw file data or a BYTE pointer? I can read the file data into a vector like this:

```
    ifstream file("image.raw", ios::binary);
    rawData.insert(rawData.begin(),
        std::istream_iterator<BYTE>(file),
        std::istream_iterator<BYTE>());
```

But I don't know now how to reshape the data manually to be a 640 * 480 matrix. Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly is a "640 * 480 matrix" ? what type should the data be in the end?

Comment: Sorry, matrix refers to a `Mat` type in OpenCV. The final data type should be unsigned char.

Comment: Why not generate the C++ code from MATLAB itself and see what it's doing?

Comment: Looks like the raw data is a 640*480 size vector of bytes that is column major on disk. You want to access it in C++ as row major and probably flip the row index (lower left corner of the image is either 0 or 479). This is pretty easy to do with a short lambda. It would be helpful if you provide what pixel on the image is accessed by say, `pixel(row, col)`  Where on the image would you want `pixel(0,0)` to be? Top left? lower left?

Comment: @G-man, I didn't know that option existed so I;m checking that out.

Comment: @doug, `pixel(0,0)` on the image is top left

Comment: if you know the size in advance you just need two nested loops read the values one by one and set the correct pixel, sorry, but without providing more information on what causes you problems I dont think you will get a better answer than that

Comment: Also, 2D arrays are normally kept in memory as 1D vectors and just accessed appropriately based on whether row or col major. Do not create a `vector<vector<BYTE>>` to access like `v[i][j]` as it's slower.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access with a lambda like this:

```
auto& pixel=[rawData, width](int row, int col) {
    return rawData[col+width*row];};
```

Alternately, you can write a function which does the same. Lambdas are short and convenient ways of creating a function.

```
BYTE& pixel(vector<BYTE>& rawData, int width, int row, int col) {
    return rawData[col+width*row];
};
```

To use the lambda:

```
auto value_at_lower_right = pixel(479,639);
```

To use the function:

```
BYTE value_at_lower_right = pixel(rawData, width, 479,639);
```

These can be used on the left side as well to change a value in the image:

```
pixel(rawData, width, 479,639) = 127;
// or, for the lambda
pixel(479,639) = 127;
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but I've been out the game for a long while. I haven't come across lamdas in C++ and even reading about them just now, I'm still confused how to implement your answer. I was guessing I'd need two FOR loops to work through the width and height. I'll try to edit my question to make it more appealing to everyone.

Comment: You will get more specific responses if you include a snippet that is compilable since it will include things like the declaration of `rawData`.  That wasn't needed for the lambda since the only operator needed was `[]` For the function you will likely need to change it.